# How to blend two different documents?

Tags: xetex, formatting, letters, scrlttr2, combine

> Below is document one with its associated `.lco` file:

---

`.lco`

---

```
\ProvidesFile{standard.lco}[%    
    2002/07/09 v0.9a LaTeX2e unsupported letter-class-option]    
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fix-cm} 
\usepackage{marvosym}
% ==================================================    
% PERSONAL DATA
% ==================================================
\setkomavar{fromname}{From Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{From Address}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{From Phone}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{From Email}
\setkomavar{place}{From Place}
\setkomavar{signature}{Signature(s)}
% ==================================================
% FORMATTING
% ==================================================
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont {Diavlo Light Regular}
\setsansfont {Gill Sans Light}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11}{16}\selectfont}
\newcommand\myname{%
    {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15.0}\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}}
}
\newcommand\mytitle{%
    \fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape Profession
}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{
    \centering
        \myname\\[5mm]
        \mytitle
}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
    \centering
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape
    {\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}}\\
    {\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone}
}   
\endinput
```

---

Document 1

---

```
\documentclass[standard,letterpaper,pagesize,UScommercial9,foldmarks=false]{scrlttr2}%backaddress=plain
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fix-cm} 
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}    
\begin{letter}{    
    Master of Provisions            \\%
    Company Name        \\%
    Company Address             \\%    
    Company Address \\%
    USA
}    
\setkomavar{subject}{Business Proposal}    
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}    

Hello, and good evening \footnote{Note well this message. It's important}. I am a businessman, and I do business.

\closing{Regards}    
\end{letter}    
\end{document}
```

> Below is document two:

---

Document 2

---

```
\documentclass[standard]{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\address{Address \\ Address \\ Address \\ Address}
\signature{Pig Master}
\date{23. May 2009}
\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{Address \\ Address \\ Address \\ Address}
    \opening{Invoice no. 1}
    My greeting
    \begin{invoice}{USD}{0}
      \ProjectTitle{Project 1}%
      \Fee{Development} {1000.00} {1}
    \end{invoice}
    \closing{I am a bumblebee}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

> I would like to know how to blend some of the features of document one
>   and its associated `.lco` file into document two; namely, how can the
>   invoice have the phone-email footer at the bottom? How can I get a
>   document-wide Diavlo Light Regular font? What about a water mark
>   titled wm.jpg?

Comment: Also, how do you get the tax listed in the invoice? What about the credit terms?

Comment: Why don't you just use document 1? By the way, you can edit your question rather than commenting on it.

Comment: Is there still interest here?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is basically, how do i get an invoice in the first doc. The answer is surprisingly simple, just load the package.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mikeBlendDocs.lco}
\ProvidesFile{mikeBlendDocs.lco}[%    
    2014/12/18 v0.1 LaTeX2e unsupported letter-class-option]    
\setkomavar{fromname}{From Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{From Address}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{From Phone}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{From Email}
\setkomavar{place}{From Place}
\setkomavar{signature}{Signature(s)}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering%
    {%
        \renewcommand{\\}{~{\large\textperiodcentered}~}%
        \usekomavar{fromaddress}%
    }\\%
    \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\quad\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}%
}%
}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[mikeBlendDocs,symbolicnames,letterpaper,pagesize,UScommercial9,foldmarks=false]{scrlttr2}%backaddress=plain
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{invoice}
\begin{document}    
\begin{letter}{    
    Master of Provisions            \\%
    Company Name        \\%
    Company Address             \\%    
    Company Address \\%
    USA
}    
\setkomavar{subject}{Business Proposal}    
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}    

Hello, and good evening \footnote{Note well this message. It's important}. I am a businessman, and I do business.
    \begin{invoice}{USD}{0}
      \ProjectTitle{Project 1}%
      \Fee{Development} {1000.00} {1}
    \end{invoice}

\closing{Regards}    
\end{letter}    
\end{document}
```